# How to create custom Error logging using ExceptionSubscriber to log JWT errors

Tags: logging, jwt, abp

I am having issues logging JWT errors.  Currently, ABP will log all JWT errors the same way, we would like to know more information on why the JWT Token failed to get data.

For example, is it a claims issue?  Is the Token expired? etc.

Here is a code sample:

```
    public class CustomExceptionSubscriber : ExceptionSubscriber
    {

    private readonly ILogger<CustomExceptionSubscriber> _logger;
    public CustomExceptionSubscriber(ILogger<CustomExceptionSubscriber> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    } 

    public async override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionNotificationContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(context.Exception.Message);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException avEx)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(avEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by catching a specific exception

```
public class CustomExceptionSubscriber : ExceptionSubscriber
{

    private readonly ILogger<CustomExceptionSubscriber> _logger;
    public CustomExceptionSubscriber(ILogger<CustomExceptionSubscriber> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    } 

    public async override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionNotificationContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(context.Exception.Message);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException avEx)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"A new Access Violation Exception has been thrown: {avEx}");
            _logger.LogInformation(avEx.Message);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"A new Security Token Validation Exception has been thrown: {e}");
            _logger.LogInformation(e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```